# Pure CSS Bulb - Two shapes change color on click

Tags: html, css

I made a bulb in pure CSS and I want the bulb to change color on click. But my bulb shape consists of two shapes, so I cannot hover over both. Is there a way to solve this without using JavaScript, sticking to CSS only? Is there maybe a way to create this yellow shape without the need to combine two? Or any other way I could have the hover effect working.

```css
.box {
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  margin-top: 8%;
  width: 600px;
  height: 600px;
  background: white;
}

#circle {
  position: absolute;
  width: 40%;
  height: 40%;
  background: yellow;
  top: 20%;
  left: 30%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

#trapezoid {
  position: absolute;
  background: yellow;
  height: 30%;
  width: 40%;
  left: 30%;
  top: 42%;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 80% 100%, 20% 100%);
}

#bottom1 {
  position: absolute;
  height: 5%;
  width: 25%;
  background: grey;
  top: 72%;
  left: 37.5%;
  z-index: 1;
}

#bottom1:before {
  content: "";
  height: 100%;
  width: 20%;
  background: grey;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 50%;
  left: -8%;
}

#bottom1:after {
  content: "";
  height: 100%;
  width: 20%;
  background: grey;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 50%;
  right: -8%;
}

#bottom2 {
  position: absolute;
  height: 5%;
  width: 22%;
  background: grey;
  top: 78%;
  left: 39%;
}

#bottom2:before {
  content: "";
  height: 100%;
  width: 20%;
  background: grey;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 50%;
  left: -8%;
}

#bottom2:after {
  content: "";
  height: 100%;
  width: 20%;
  background: grey;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 50%;
  right: -8%;
}

#bottom3 {
  position: absolute;
  height: 5%;
  width: 18%;
  background: grey;
  top: 84%;
  left: 41%;
  z-index: 1;
}

#bottom3:before {
  content: "";
  height: 100%;
  width: 20%;
  background: grey;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 50%;
  left: -8%;
}

#bottom3:after {
  content: "";
  height: 100%;
  width: 20%;
  background: grey;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 50%;
  right: -8%;
}

#shine {
  width: 20%;
  height: 20%;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 50%;
  top: 20%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 18%;
}

.halfCircle {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border-radius: 0 0 90px 90px;
}

#halfCircle {
  height: 45px;
  width: 90px;
  border-radius: 0 0 90px 90px;
  background: black;
  margin: 0 auto;
  top: 88%;
  position: relative;
}

.drop {
  width: 5%;
  height: 5%;
  position: absolute;
  border: 15px solid orange;
}

#left {
  left: 38%;
  top: 45%;
  border-radius: 50% 50% 0 50%;
}

#left:after {
  content: "";
  height: 110px;
  width: 24px;
  border: 15px solid orange;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  top: 100%;
}

#right {
  right: 38%;
  top: 45%;
  border-radius: 50% 50% 50% 0;
}

#circle:hover {
  background: red;
}

#trapezoid:hover {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class='box'>

  <div id='circle'>
    <div id='shine'></div>
  </div>

  <div id='trapezoid'></div>


  <div id='bottom1'></div>
  <div id='bottom2'></div>
  <div id='bottom3'></div>

  <div id='halfCircle'></div>

  <div class='drop' id='left'></div>
  <div class='drop' id='right'></div>


  <div id='wire'></div>




</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't have to apply the `:hover` directly to the element that you want to change.  You can hoist it to a wrapping element and apply it there.

Considering your example, your selectors would likely be something along the lines of:

```
.box:hover #circle {
  background: red;
}

.box:hover #trapezoid {
  background: red;
}
```

Consider this concrete example.  Hovering either of the nested `<div>` cause the sibling `<div>` to also change color because `#container` is being `:hover`ed.

```css
#foo,
#bar {
  height: 20px;
  background-color: green;
  border: 1px solid white;
}

#foo:hover,
#bar:hover {
  background-color: blue;
  border: 1px dashed yellow;
}

#container:hover #foo,
#container:hover #bar {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="foo">foo</div>
  <div id="bar">bar</div>
</div>
```